# Saving data in datastore then in table-vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to save all data firstly in a data structure and then save this data structure in a table in data base.

I have a process, in which I should write rows very often in a table. I want to save these rows in a data structure, and then save this datastucture only one time in table in access

Comment: Open an updateable recordset from the table, add your records, then call `Update` on the recordset.  Eg. see second code example here: http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/ado_recordset_object_update_method.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create your own data structures by using

- the [Type statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278730.aspx) or
- by [creating Class Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195443.aspx).

The former is simpler, the latter more flexible.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to serialize your data structure into a table row, so you will have to write that code yourself, either by using an INSERT statement or a parameterized append query.

Comment: Are they faster than as I open the table for each row and write on it?  I should write on a table more than 100000

Comment: @Kaja: I doubt it, but you'd have to profile both solutions to be sure.